# Can I ask a question?

Tags: support

I'm a C programming beginner. is this the right place to ask questions for help of this site is just for experienced programmers?

Answer (score 5):

There is an official list of things that are [on-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for the site. Implementation questions should go on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Your level of experience doesn't matter.

What all Stack Exchange sites are about is getting **expert** answers to your question.

However, you do have to find the right site for your question. Check the `\help\on-topic` page for each site to see if your question fits.

Ours is [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Stack Overflows is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)